# ImportError: no mudule named ini

Tags: python, pythonpath

I have a directory structure like

```
akom
   DB
     DBinit.py 
     __init__.py
     server.py 

   Configuration(dir)
   urls.py
   settings.py 
   manage.py 
   ini.py
   __init__.py
```

I have set the PYTHONPATH in my .bashrc as `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/dir1/dir2/`

Inside dir2 akom reside.

I am importing the `ini.py` on `server.py` like `import ini`  but i am getting the error that

```
ImportError: No module named ini
```

Please tell me where i am going wrong .?

Comment: try this: `from akom.Configuration import ini` edit: also, did you source your bashrc? `. ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `akom` is a package itself, you need to reference modules inside that package by the package name first - e.g. by using `import akom.ini` instead of `import ini`.

Update: Reading above, it's somewhat unclear if `ini.py` is in the `Configuration` directory - if it is you will need to do `import akom.Configuration.ini`.

Comment: Oh i forgot to tell you __init__ is also in akom folder

Comment: @masterofdestiny: In that case you need to `import akom.ini`, not `import ini`

Comment: What do you see if you `echo $PYTHONPATH`?  Also, is `ini.py` in the `Configuration` directory, or at the same level?